# New Google play console - managed publishing for first app release issue for multiple release at a time

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have put the same build (v1.0.0) build for review in both Alpha testing review and as well as production review while managing publishing to save time for the review process. Both reviews are already completed and ready to release/publish now.

My problem is, I don't want to publish the Production release now, but want to publish an Alpha testing release only. But when I try to press the publish button "Review & Publish" in the Manage publishing sections, it says

> All changes will be visible to users. This can't be undone

and both releases will be published at the same time

[image]

I have also tried to disable the managing publishing feature, suggested by google support personnel, but the below pop-up message displayed the pending release will be published immediately and can not be undone.

[image]

I am stuck as I neither can discard the releases nor can approve any release as I don't want to publish the first production release now.

Comment: This really sucks, facing the same issue. I have app on both open track and production track, I need to publish the open track first but seems like that review and publish button will also publish the production track which I am not allowed to do right now, I'm out of options here :/

Comment: Even if publishing just one release, it would be so much clearer it said 'Confirm publish to open testing | closed testing | production'.

The language used is ambiguous and suggests it is about to publish to production. Could do with some UX love...

Comment: commenting from 2023, it still like that. It publishes everything on the list.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem. I contacted google support through chat and the specialist said that it is not possible to select which release to publish and clicking the publish button will publish everything that is on the list.

Comment: This is such a poor UX if you ask me and I am really disappointed by Google in this regard...

Comment: So I have contacted them not to ask if it is possible, because clearly it is not, but to REQUEST the implementation of this feature. I can't even possible think that Google and the PO/PM/Owner of the PlayConsole product decided to push this new version without thinking of parallel managing between tracks. A bit if not totally outrageous.

Comment: I am still facing this issue in 2023, this is completely mind blowing. I had to set a small foreign country in Production not concerned by our app in order to publish every channels and get the closed track published... And that only works because we are okay with the app not being actually released in our country just yet, I can't imagine if we needed the older version live.
Google really needs to take action on this one, this is indeed outrageous.

Comment: I went back to production line and paused the launch. Then went to publish overview and released the now only beta publish.

Comment: Nearly 2024 and this is still an issue :/

Comment: Just ran into this. Unbelievable. Use case:

1) we want to synchronize Play Store and App Store releases, so managed publishing is on

2) we're running a continuous closed beta and need those releases to go out and not be blocked

Blows my mind this isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Halt rollout" button on the production build if didn't publish to 100% user base at once. This will remove it from review, and you will be able to send only other tracks.

If your builds are already accepted - discard all accepted data and move them back to the "Ready for review" state.

Comment: Could you elaborate on discard accepted data? Please, I'm thinking this might be the only actual available option right now, but historically removing anything from Google play has been impossible

Comment: @martinseal1987 I mean, when the app has not yet been published, the only working solution appears to be: 1. Have managed publishing activated, 2. Always submit the app for review with a rollout less than 100%. When the rollout is not 100%, you can see the "Halt rollout" button, which effectively removes this version from being approved and waiting for publication.