# Google Play Console - Publish only certain changes with managed publishing

Tags: android, publish, google-play-console

I have an app that has been reviewed by Google and is ready to be published. Managed publishing is turned on. However, I am not quite ready to release it to the public yet. In the meanwhile, I would like to add a new build to a closed testing track. The problem is that when I add the new test build, it also goes to the list of "Changes ready to publish". I see a general button to "Publish changes" but not a way to publish certain changes.

How can I publish my test build without also releasing the production app at this time? If I turn off managed publishing now, will it automatically publish all current pending changes?

Comment: My searching skills seemed to have declined. I was able to find the same scenario asked here after posting the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047233/new-google-play-console-managed-publishing-for-first-app-release-issue-for-mul?rq=1. It seems like this is not possible which is completely befuddling to me.

Comment: I recently had the same issue and managed to do it, here is the answer: stackoverflow.com/a/76779538/2734478

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible but there is a walk around to do a similar thing:

- You can release the first build with 100% rollout
- Then release the 2nd build with 99.9999% rollout (this will rollout to all users)
- When you want to release the first build just halt the the 2nd build release

Answer (score -2):

In case you want to test multiple functions please create separate tracks for Closed Testing section, note that this track submission have to pass the Google review.
If you don't want the changes to go to Google review and available to user you can publish this in internal track.

My recommendation is look at firebase app distribution, its more scalable to allow you to distribute your apps specific revisions to dedicated testers groups you create.

Comment: Why has this "answer" not been removed? Please don't take this advice