# How to publish only one change?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

We're trying to publish new Alpha version to Google Play, but we only have an option to publish to production as well. Production version (2.8.10) is buggy and not suitable for release. How can we publish Alpha only?

[image]

Comment: I recently had the same issue and managed to do it, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76779538/2734478